# releasing all cells in tableview ios iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, tableview

i got mem leaking problem discovered with profiling in xcode. The problem it's quite easy but i can't understand how fix it:

Consider a uiviewcontroller with 2 button and a tableview.
button1=load JSON data from server and add cells to tableview then [tableview reloadData]

button2=load JSON data from another server and add cells to tableview then reload.

ok the problem is in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
....
.....
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringpath];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img;
if(!data) img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"small.jpg"];
else img= [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
cell.imageView.image = img;
```

Ok now if i start to switch with 2 button everytime i switch i got leaking from UIImage, so i think i need to "purge" (release) all cells data before reloading?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be releasing the `img` object after setting it in `cell.imageView.image`. I prefer to `autorelease` on the same line as it makes it easier for me to keep track.

```
UIImage *img;
if(!data) img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"small.jpg"];
else img= [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
cell.imageView.image = img;
```

As mentioned in another answer, you can save yourself the pain by not using the `initWithData` call, but instead `imageWithData`.

The cells will take care of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not releasing `img`,plz use below

```
if (!data) 
{
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"small.jpg"];
    cell.imageView.image = img;
}
else 
{
    img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    cell.imageView.image = img;
    [img release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would replace this line:

```
else img= [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

with:

```
else img= [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to allocate memory for UIImage. You can perform the above implementation as follows :

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

Try this.

Comment: Thx Stone.. I come from c/c++ and to me it's more easy to think about stack and heap. If you allocate in stack,stack will be cleared when you switch context and for heap every new you need a delete. For now memory management in ios still a little confusing. I readed memory-management from apple but the rule "if you alloc you release" it's not always true. Maybe a day i will stop to fall in error like this. Thx again.

Comment: After some practice and reading you'll definitely feel comfortable with this concept. :)